# Asymptotically optimal algorithms

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

Suppose one has an algorithm to solve a problem using at most f(n) computations with size of input n. How to prove, if such is the case, that this algorithm is the fastest possible for solving this problem?

I am aware of the open P!=NP problem, but I assume there are nontrivial problems where it has been proved that no faster algorithm exist? Which are such examples, and how is it proved?

Comment: Curiously, there is a large class of problems, including many known NP-complete ones where _Levin's optimal search theorem_ provides a concrete algorithm, with guaranteed optimal _asymptotic_ running time. The catch is that it is essentially impossible to _analyze_ the running time of this algorithm without already knowing what the fastest possible running time is -- and also that Levin's algorithm has gigantic constant factors in its running time (where "gigantic" usually means "more than a googol").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no general way, but only a wealth of techniques. Here are some examples:

- You prove that $f(n)$ is the minimum time required to read the input. For example, shortest path problem cannot be solved in less than $O(V + E)$.
- You prove that an algorithm with fewer will not get enough data about the input to output the correct solution. Thus, once can change the input in a way that changes the result without the algorithm "noticing" the difference. An example of this would be the proof that sorting cannot be done in less than $O(n \log n)$.
- You prove that an algorithm running in less time will lead to an existence of an algorithm that would solve a problem in less than the optimal time (e.g. sorting in less than $O(n \log n)$). This is achieved via reduction.
- You prove that the size of the output is in worst case as big as $f(n)$ therefore, one cannot take shorter time to compute it. For example, outputting the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number cannot be solved in less than $O(2^{n})$ since the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci is ~ $\phi^{n}$ where $\phi$ is around $1.6$

There are more techniques, but those are some examples off the top of my head.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, the size of the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci numbers is exponential in the length (read log) of n, therefore it cannot be computed in less than $O(n)$ not $O(2^{n})$.

Comment: Your fourth example doesn't seem correct. The size of the output here is $\log_2 F_n$, not $F_n$. Binary exponentiation on the matrix $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right]$ should allow you to compute the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number in time $O(n)$.

Comment: For your fourth example, the $n$th Fibonacci number has $O(n)$ bits, so the $n$th Fibonacci number cannot be computed in $o(n)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan How do you get $O(n)$?

Comment: @Zach: hmm. I think I need to retract that. $F_n$ turns out to be the bottom right entry of $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right]^n$, which can be computed using about $\log_2 n$ matrix multiplications using binary exponentiation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). The entries can be described using at most $n$ bits, so the total time needed is $O(M(n) \log n)$ where $M(n)$ is the complexity of whatever matrix multiplication algorithm you're using. I guess you can't do better than $O(n^2 \log n)$ this way.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Actually, if you use fast Fourier transforms for multiplication, you can describe the running time of your algorithm by $T(n) \le T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + cn\lg{n}\lg\lg{n}$, which implies $T(n) = O(n\lg{n}\lg\lg{n})$.

Comment: You both are absolutely correct, I was mixing the length of the input and the value of the input. I guess I should never post when I'm sleepy! Edited my answer.

Comment: "less than $O(.)$" is not a very meaningful phrase. You should write "in o(.)$" instead. Also, note that the lower bound for sorting only applies to a certain setting and to comparisons.

Comment: @Qiaochu Complexity of matrix multiplication does not play a role here; we are multiplying matrices of fixed size, so this takes constant number of arithmetic operations. The problem is with integer multiplication, and it can be done using FFT, the [fastest currently known method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm) takes $n \log n 2^{O(\log^{\ast} n)}$ time.

Answer (score 4):

Sorting by comparisons can't be done in $o(n\log n)$ because $k$ comparisons can't distinguish among more than $2^k$ orderings, and there are $n!$ possible orderings, and Stirling's formula gives you $\log(n!)$ is on the order of $n\log n$. (edited in response to spot-on comments by Raphael)

Comment: "faster than $O(.)$" is not very meaningful; you mean "in o(.)$. Note also that the famous bound only applies to comparison sorts.