# What does asymptotically proportional mean?

Tags: asymptotics

In an article about Metcalfe's law, I've read that $n(n-1)/2$ is *asymptotically proportional* to $n^2$.

What does this mean?

PS:
I did find [asymptotically **optimal**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181391/what-does-asymptotically-optimal-mean-for-an-algorithm) but I'm not sure if they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proportional to $n^2$ when $n$ tends to infinity. In other words, the larger $n$, the closer the expression at hand is to $cn^2$, for some constant $c$.

In [Landau's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), $\dfrac {n(n-1)}2=\Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer

Answer (score 1):

The limit calculation
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{n^2} = 
\frac{1}{2}
$$
says that for large $n$ the expression is approximately proportional to $n^2$ with proportionality constant $1/2$.